# Syntastic C configuration file

Tags: c, vim, syntastic

In an attempt to add the include paths to Syntastic (3.6.0-106; Vim 7.3), to stop it from giving a fatal error at the first include it can't find, I tried creating a `.syntastic_c_config` file. There's not a lot of information on how this is supposed to work, but there are references out there and I followed their example:

```
-I/path/to/include
-I/you/get/the/idea
-L/some/library
-lfoo
-lbar
-DHAVE_SOME_FLAG
-pedantic
-Wall
-std=c99
```

That is, one compiler argument per line.

This has had the effect of removing virtually all error checking, unless I force it with `:SynasticCheck` -- at which point, it seems to work a *little* bit better, but not exactly how I'd expect. However, either way, if I `:echo g:syntastic_c_config_file` (or any other option that I'm expecting to be set), Vim just gives me an undefined variable warning.

I'm clearly doing something fundamentally wrong, but I'm not really sure what!

Comment: Why do you expect `g:syntastic_c_config_file` to be set if you didn't set it?  Have you tried enabling debugging to see what's going on?  Did you read the wiki page for the gcc checker?

Comment: I have read https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C%3A---gcc where it suggests that `g:syntastic_c_config_file` defaults to `.syntastic_c_config`. Indeed, when this file exists the behaviour is different, so it's definitely doing something regardless of me explicitly setting the variable... I wasn't aware of a debugging mode; I'll try that.

Comment: With `let syntastic_debug=63`, it appears as though Syntastic *is* correctly opening the `.syntastic_c_config` file (regardless of it being unset) and passes those options into the call to `gcc` (without setting the `g:syntastic_c_*` options explicitly). The output was complaining that my `-L` and `-l` flags were useless: when I removed them from the config, it all started working.

Comment: According to the maintainer, syntastic doesn't use the `g:syntastic_*` variables to keep state.  It uses them to update its internal states _at the right moment_.  They are still taken into account if you set them.  As for the contents of the config file, you'd typically take the incantation to compile files from the `Makefile`, and keep only the compilation flags (`-l` and `-L` are linker flags).  Some checkers can use compilation databases, but you need to configure them for that.  This is described in the wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Syntastic will source the configuration file without explicitly setting the respective variable. Moreover, the contents of the configuration file are not passed into any `syntastic_c_*` variables, but nonetheless passed into the call to `gcc`. Syntastic is also clever enough to backtrace to look for the configuration file (e.g., it will go up levels until it finds it, so you can keep the `.syntastic_c_config` in your project root).

As to why it was failing, the debug log was showing that my compiler was ignoring the library flags (`-L/some/path` and `-lfoo`) and that was blocking Syntastic from any further syntax checking. Removing those lines from my config file solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but I stumbled upon here searching for an answer to the same problem. Looks like Syntastic has changed quite a bit. Documentation listed above by OP is not valid anymore. Current (as of 18 July 2020) documentation is at: https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic-checkers.txt

To add include paths to 'gcc' checker, you would need to create a file with your include dirs, one per line, preceded by '-I'. For example, in */home/user/.syntastic_c_config_file* add:

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0/include
-I/usr/include/boost
```

Then in your {vimrc} file (usually, ~/.vimrc), add one line:

```
let g:syntastic_c_config_file='/home/user/.syntastic_c_config_file'
```

Syntastic has become more powerful now and contains many options in the above linked documentation.